# Craft 4 Upgrade - Migration issue

Tags: craft4, upgrades

I am SO close to getting my Craft 3.8.7 upgraded to 4.0.  Now, I'm getting an error when it tries to run a migration. I read in the docs that there were a couple of tables that were deprecated, so I was surprised to see an error related to a dependency with the `entrydrafts` table.  I looked for any notes on this migration but could not find anything.  Here's the error:

```
    Database Exception: SQLSTATE[2BP01]: Dependent objects still exist: 7 ERROR: cannot drop table entrydrafts because other objects depend on it
DETAIL: constraint workflow_submissions_draftId_fk on table workflow_submissions depends on table entrydrafts
HINT: Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
The SQL being executed was: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "entrydrafts"

Migration: craft\migrations\m210624_222934_drop_deprecated_tables

Output:

> dropping {{%entrydrafterrors}} if it exists ... done (time: 0.009s)
> dropping {{%entryversionerrors}} if it exists ... done (time: 0.004s)
> dropping {{%entrydrafts}} if it exists ...Exception: SQLSTATE[2BP01]: Dependent objects still exist: 7 ERROR: cannot drop
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the error, the `entrydrafts` table cannot be dropped because the `workflow_submissions` table depends on it. That looks like it belongs to the [Workflow plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/workflow?craft4), so try uninstalling the Workflow plugin *before* running the migration, which should remove that table and its dependency.

Comment: Thank you Ben. Removing the plugin was one of the first things I did.  Are there steps that I can do to resolve the conflicts in such a way that Craft is happy and will not try to run the migration?

Comment: Does the table still exist in the DB? If so, try dropping it manually.

Comment: I deleted the workflow_submissions table manually, but the migration still failed.  It looks like the m210624_222934_drop_deprecated_tables.php migration uses a 'drop if exists' class method but the method does not do a DROP CASCADE.  Unless I've missed something.

Comment: What error message is it failing with now?

Comment: Sorry Ben, I got to it this morning and I wasn't getting the error anymore, somehow, the migration must have completed properly. I had manually dropped the workflow_submissions table... maybe that removed the dependencies for the depreciated tables?  I've been working this out on a development server (going from 3.4 to 4.4.8), so that I can work through it quickly on the live server.  I did this time through incrementally, but I'd like to go directly from Craft 3.4 to 3.8.7. Do you think that would work?

Comment: I would think so.